# IOS Launch Screen и Пароль

Tags: ios, swift

Есть такая задача, на IOS приложении нужно запускать Launch Screen, но только в том случае если пароль который записан в UserDelaults неустановлен, вот на Android я делал такую задачу и там было все легко, но на IOS к Launch Screen нельзя прицепить controller поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Screen показывается во время загрузки приложения, потому на него и не получится навесить контроллер, в вашем случае я делал примерно так:

Есть экран для входа, я беру у него бекграунд без елементов куда можно что-то вводить или взаимодейсквовать, и делаю его лаунч скрином. Потом в сториборде(если такой есть, мало ли) верстаю такую же вьюху только с полями для логина(например) и все красиво подменяется. А если данные уже есть то можно программно заменить инишиал контроллер и показать юзера уже залогиненым.